# How to change DataGridView cell image on mouseover?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I am painting an image in a datagridviews columns cells like so:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
    If e.ColumnIndex = 20 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString) Then

            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
            Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\me\Desktop\glass.png")
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, e.CellBounds.Left + 10, e.CellBounds.Top + 5, 25, 25)
            e.Handled = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Is it possible to switch the image to another if I hover over one of the cells (just for the hovered cell not all cells)?

Comment: CellEnter (with brief delay?) then CellLeave to undo.  Unrelated, but if you are showing the same image or a small set of images, you should load them into an array or list rather than create a new one each time.  Every cell does need its own personal copy of `glass.png` and you wont have to worry about disposing of them.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I am assuming cell paint gets re-fired on enter and leave?

Comment: No, that wont work - those fire when you activate the cell. Sorry, I was more focused on the other tidbits

Comment: CellMouseLeave and CellMouseEnter are what I was thinking.  yuk.... ^ `Every cell does **not** need its own personal copy...`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you mean by loading them into an array? Do you mean instead of loading from file? Would love to optimize this as best as possible.

Comment: how many different images are you working with?

Comment: It's just one image painted into all datagridview rows.

Comment: The Q asks how to 'change it to another'.  Is the data just in the DGV or elsewhere like a list or datatable?

Comment: The data itself is in in a datatable. The image is just painted there if that cells value is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, your code is creating a new image for each cell where that image is to be displayed.  Each cell doesn't really need its own personal image object.

Also, rather than loading from disk (which means the file could be deleted or moved), you could add the image to resources.  Getting it from there will ***still*** create a new image object each time, so store them in an array:

```
Private ImgBalls As Image()
```

Then somewhere like FormLoad:

```
' ToDo: add a BulletColor enum for indexing
ImgBalls = New Image() {
                        My.Resources.ballblack, My.Resources.ballblue,
                        My.Resources.ballgreen, My.Resources.ballorange,
                        My.Resources.ballred, My.Resources.ballpurple,
                        My.Resources.ballyellow
                        }
```

Then using it *like* a hover (no delay):

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellMouseEnter(etc etc etc...
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return

    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = ImgBalls(6)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dgv1_CellMouseLeave(etc etc etc...
    If e.RowIndex < 0 OrElse dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then Return

    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
        dgv1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = ImgBalls(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

This changes a default black bullet to yellow when the mouse is over it:

[image]

Note that if a null value is invalid, rather than an image you can also use `CellErrorText` to provide a red exclamation and some text.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I am trying to accomplish, but couldn't find much info on. Thanks for taking the time to help out, much appreciated!

Comment: All the rows are using the same black bullet image and the same yellow one.

Comment: You could implement the standard 400ms hover delay by setting a flag and starting a timer in CellMouseEnter, then actually set the image in CellMouseMove.  Seems a tad overkill for ~400ms diff between this and a real hover