# User Interface disappearing with error : out of memory

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a problem which is that after leaving the program for a certain period let's say for 5 minutes or more the user interface starts to disappear, such as: buttons, labels ... etc

Then if I try to click on anything It shows me an error as follows: `out of memory`

I use custom controls which are: Bunifu_UI_v1.5.3

But I use simple things like datagridview and datetimepicker

But I do not think the problem from it  because almost everything i use is the orginal controls  by the original visual studio.

There is lots of code like this:

```
Private Sub close_butt_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles close_butt.MouseEnter
    close_butt.Image = My.Resources.Close_white_32
    close_butt.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
Private Sub close_butt_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles close_butt.MouseLeave
    close_butt.Image = My.Resources.Close_white_32
    close_butt.BackColor = Nothing
End Sub
```

this is the error :

[image]

and this is the full error text :

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
HResult=-2147024882
Message=Out of memory.
StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHdcInternal(IntPtr hdc)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectDrawItem(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmOwnerDraw(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDrawItem(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmSetFocus(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: Your post is confusing: is it all standard controls or are there custom ones?  Are you doing any special drawing/painting anywhere (`shops_diagram` makes that seem likely)?  Generally it sounds like an out of resources issue (no more handles available for controls) which in turn generally means a leak and likely from not disposing of things.  Such things are app-wide maladies and wont be the result if that code.

Comment: BTW, Visual Studio comes with some great profiling tools to show you pretty much where leaks and such are.

Comment: @Plutonix
I'm using the standard controls except the `datagridview` and the `datetimepicker` , and i don't know if its form not  disposing ,Because the problem also occurs when I run the program and leave it without entering anything or doing anything.
and can you give me a name for one of this tools or link.
thank you.

Comment: **Are you doing any special drawing/painting anywhere (`shops_diagram` makes that seem likely)?**   If it does it without doing anything at all, it is something you doing somewhere. Note that forms are resources that ought to be disposed, and the code shown does not (it looks like it could be a default form ref).   All the profiling tools are IN VS.  Mine are under the Analyze menu but that may vary by version.  There is far too little relevant info in the post to be much help other than general guidelines.

Comment: @Plutonix No I'm not using any thing need to drawing/ painting.
here is the full code for my main form, if you can look at it i'll be grateful
http://text-share.com/view/2f66347b

Comment: Just scrolling thru it quickly I see several things, but I think `the problem also occurs when I run the program and leave it without entering anything or doing anything` is not entirely accurate.  Start it and let it run but walk away from the computer - don do anything at all.  Will it run longer than the 5 mins?  I cant post an answer because as I already said, the problem code is not in the post

Comment: @Plutonix its not 5 mins exactly , its happening after while, but i'm pretty sure after 5 mins, and yes its also happening if I start it and let it run and walk away from the computer, what i can post to you to help me to  figure out the problem ??
i can give you the whole code if you have time to help me , i worked on it for more than 4 months, I don't know what to do I'm powerless.

Comment: @Plutonix Hello again, 
unfortunately the problem not solved, but now its take longer time to disappearing, its take more than 10 minutes, i change the most `pictureboxes` with 2 `panels` for each ( visible:/ True-False), I'm getting crazy i dont now where is the problem and my diagnostic tools not workong in my VS 2015 don't Know why. this is my code now  :http://text-share.com/view/6b99b14f

Comment: Yes, thats why the answer starts with `At least one of the problems is ...`.  With code like that, it seems very likely that there was more than one cause.  Visual Studio's analysis tools WILL find them for you and tell you how bad it is

Comment: @Plutonix , as i said in the last comment the diagnostic tools not working in my VS 2015 don't know why, can you point to me Where can the problems be i'll try to change the code way : :text-share.com/view/6b99b14f.
thank you

Comment: Sorry, thats not how the site works.  But, anything which has a `Dispose` method must be disposed of (use `Using` blocks) which includes bitmaps, DBConnections, DBCommands, DataReaders, streams and many other things.  You *might* be able to get someone to do a complete code review without a mod deleting it if you post a question and put a bounty on it. `freelancer.com` is another option.  As a note, `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` defaults to true for a reason, crossing *that* line is asking for trouble

Comment: @Plutonix , thank you for your advice's and Time, I appreciate It.

Comment: @Plutonix I found the problem, all this happens because of  `Timer2`for the clock !! , thanks again for every thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least one of the problems is in code like this (and there is a **lot of it**):

```
Private Sub stores_but_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles stores_but.MouseEnter
    stores_but.Image = My.Resources.Stores_1
    Stores_Panel.Visible = True
End Sub
Private Sub stores_but_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles stores_but.MouseLeave
    stores_but.Image = My.Resources.Stores
    Stores_Panel.Visible = False
End Sub
```

`My.Resources` is not a collection of anything including images or bitmaps.  If you drill into those you'll see code like this:

```
Friend ReadOnly Property Stores() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Get
        Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("Stores", resourceCulture)
        Return CType(obj,System.Drawing.Bitmap)
    End Get
End Property
```

It is **creating a new Bitmap object** from data stored elsewhere.  But `Bitmaps` are a resource which must be disposed of when you are done with it and the Enter/Leave code is not doing that.

It can be worse in cases of a [series of repeating images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537488/1070452) such as a status or set of Yes/No images: you dont need 10 or 20 unique images, but that is the result of getting each one from `My.Resources`.  Timers that update a status using images directly from `Myresources` can run out of handles very quickly.

To fix *that problem* load the images into an array or list and use them instead:

```
Private StatusImgs As Image()
```

Elsewhere in form load perhaps:

```
StatusImgs = New Image() {
                        My.Resources.ballblack, My.Resources.ballblue,
                        My.Resources.ballgreen,
                        My.Resources.ballorange, My.Resources.ballpurple,
                        My.Resources.ballred, My.Resources.ballyellow
                        }
```

Usage:

```
myBtn.Image = StatusImgs(0)
```

Now, there will be a total of **one** (1) green ball image used in the entirety of my form.  You can make the code more readable using an enum:

```
Private Enum Status
    Away 
    Busy 
    IgnoringYou
    Dead
    ...
End Enum

myBtn.Image = StatusImgs(Status.Busy)
```

Comment: thank you vary much you made my day, you are genus, I'm so grateful, really thank you.